# What does (id & 12) evaluate to?

Tags: c#, if-statement, evaluation

I understand it is a simple question. Can anyone explain what the below 'if' does.
Let's assume `id = 0;`

```
private bool item;

if (item = ((id & 12) == 12))
    ret = 1;
```

1. Does `(id & 12)` evaluate to `(0+12)`? If yes, `12 == 12` becomes true.
2. Does this check if `item` is equal to true?

Comment: `((id & 12) == 12)` is `true` for any binary number `id` that has a 1 in the 8's column and a 1 in the 4's column.  Here are all the true results in the range [-40, 40].  `-36 -35 -34 -33 -20 -19 -18 -17 -4 -3 -2 -1 12 13 14 15 28 29 30 31`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is the bitwise *and* operator. It keeps only those bits which are 1 in both operands.

- `0 & 0 == 0`
- `0 & 1 == 0`
- `1 & 0 == 0`
- `1 & 1 == 1`

12 in binary is `1100` and 0 in binary is `0000`, so `0 & 12 == 0`.

Which input gives you 12? Well, any input where bits 2 and 3 are set, so for example `1111` (15, 0xF), `1101` (13, 0xD), `1110` (14, 0xE), and of course `1100` (12, 0xC) itself. But many other inputs are possible, e.g. `11100` (28, 0x1C) or `11101` (29, 0x1D).

Writing in hexadecmial notation is more compact and makes it easier to see if an input matches. 12 in hex is `0xC`. Any other hexadecimal number with `C`, `D`, `E`, or `F` at the least significant position will satisfy your condition.

Note that inputs such as `0101` (5) will fail the test, because `0101 & 1100 == 0100` (5 & 12 == 4).

`item` is assigned the result of the bitwise and and this result is then used as a condition for your `if` statement.

Comment: So, IF condition ((id & 12) == 12) becomes true when input ID is in the range (12 13 14 15 28 29 30 31). Which evaluates to if (item = true). In turn which would set ret to value 1.  Is my understanding rite? Thank you.

Comment: @Sarahrb I don't know where you got "range 12 to 31". You haven't specified the type of `id`, but if it is a 32 bit integer, the range is way larger and 4092 (0xffc) would be a valid input, as would 131068 (0x1fffc) or 268435452 (0xffffffc). But yes, it will set `item` to true or false and only if item=true, then `ret = 1`.